# Blunders that they didn't realise for some time

Tags: grandmaster, master-games, blunder

Any high-level GM games where somebody makes a big blunder but was in blissful ignorance about how bad the move was until several moves after the blunder?

EDIT thanks to comment: classical time format, not blitz (where blunders are common)

Comment: You could probably find hundreds of lichess Blitz games, or blunders happening in mutual time trouble.

Are you asking for classical time controls tournament games?

Comment: @Hauptideal yes pretty much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this has happened, but it depends on your definitions. With the definition that "a blunder is a move that changes the game-theoretic state of the game" (e.g. "draw" to "loss" or "win" to "draw"), then here's an [example](https://chessbase.in/news/Grischuk-versus-Ding-Liren-World-Cup-2019) where both Ding Liren and Alexander Grischuk were blissfully unaware of the blunder until after the end of the game.

```
[FEN ""]
[White "Grischuk, Alexander"]
[WhiteElo "2759"]
[Black "Ding, Liren"]
[BlackElo "2811"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[startply "26"]

1. d4 Nf6 
2. c4 e6 
3. Nf3 d5 
4. g3 dxc4 
5. Bg2 a6 
6. O-O Nc6 
7. e3 Rb8 
8. Nfd2 e5 
9. Bxc6+ bxc6 
10. dxe5 Ng4 
11. Nxc4 Be6 
12. Qe2 h5 
13. Rd1 Qc8 
14. Qf3? Bd5 
15. Rxd5 cxd5 
16. Qxd5 Qf5! {Black threatens ...Qxf2+ and mate.} 
17. f3! {Both Grischuk and Ding Liren saw this far and could not see a refutation of this move.} Qc2! {Black threatens ...Qxc1+, and ...Qf2+ followed by mate.} 
18. Qc6+! {18.Nbd2? Qd1+ 19. Kg2 Qe2+ wins. White has to move the Queen so that the d2-knight is no longer pinned, and Nf1 becomes possible.} Kd8 
19. Nbd2 Qd1+ 
20. Nf1 {If White gets a single free move here, 21. Bd2 intending 22. Ba5 wins.} Nxh2! {20...Rh6? 21. Qe4 Nxh2? 22. Qh4+ and Qxh2 wins for White.} 
21. Kxh2 {Just to illustrate how difficult the position is, see if you can calculate how Black wins after 21. Bd2.} Rh6!! {And Black wins because of the dual threats of ...Rxc6 and ...Qxf1. Comparatively 21...Qxf1? 22. e6 gives White enough counterplay to force a draw.}
```

Grischuk (White) went 14. Qf3? allowing Ding a game-winning continuation beginning with 14...Bd5, that was however not easy to spot by an unassisted human. After seven minutes Ding played ("blundered") 14...Rb6 and the game was eventually drawn.

However: given the complexity of the variation and how hard it is for a human to spot, can you fairly call 14. Qf3 or 14...Rb6 blunders?

Comment: Can't figure out how to add the correct move numbers to the diagram, if anyone can please go ahead and edit the post.

Comment: There is no way to start at a random number with the replayer as is, to my knowledge.  The only real solution is to put in the entire game and use [startply "x"] beneath the FEN.

Comment: @RewanDemontay, I added the whole game, but the [startply] param doesn't really do it for me? In the PGN the Param 'PlyCount' is mentioned for half moves, but that doesn't work either :-|

Comment: @ITM It counts by half moves, aka a ply. You put in the move number instead.